# Having issues displaying sqlite db data in nativescript application

Tags: javascript, sqlite, nativescript

My app has a scoreboard page that is supposed to fetch data from sqlite db and display it onNavigatingTo page in a ListView but it does not do it as expected.

The xml page to display the results:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo">

<ActionBar title="Scoreboard">
  <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back" tap="homeTap"/>
</ActionBar>

<StackLayout orientation="vertical">        
    <Label text="Your Performance Sheet"></Label>
    <ListView items= "{{results}}" > 
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <Label text="{{testname}}"/>
            <Label text="{{score}}"/>
            <Label text="{{percent}}"/>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>

</Page>
```

The scoreboard-view-model:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
var ObservableArray = require("data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

function scoreViewModel (database) {

var viewModel = new Observable();

viewModel.results = new ObservableArray([]);

viewModel.select = function () {
    this.results = new ObservableArray([]);
    database.all("SELECT * FROM scores").then(rows => {

    for (var row in rows) {         
        this.results.push(rows[row]); 
    }
    }, error => {
        console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    })
}   
viewModel.select();

return viewModel;       
}

exports.scoreViewModel = scoreViewModel;
```

I am selecting all the data from the scores table and pushing to viewModel.results array which is already bound to the view.

The scoreboard.js :

```
var observable = require("data/observable");
var scoreViewModel = require("./scoreboard-view-model").scoreViewModel;
var page;
var Sqlite = require("nativescript-sqlite");

exports.onNavigatingTo = function (args) {
page = args.object;


(new Sqlite("scoreboard.db")).then(db => {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scores (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, testname TEXT, score TEXT, percent TEXT)")
    .then(id => {
        page.bindingContext = scoreViewModel(db);           
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    });
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
}
```

Someone please help me get the data to show up in the list view.

Comment: Hey Dammy, did you confirm that data is coming back from your database correctly? Just wondering if that’s the problem or whether this is a binding issue. At a glance everything you have here looks reasonable.

Comment: Yes TJ, data is coming from the database, i logged it to the console to be sure. It's working now, got it to display by editing the view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it work by editing the scoreboard-view-model.js file, precisely in the viewModel.Select function:

```
viewModel.select = function () {
    //the line below was changed to this...
    //testname, score, and percent are column names in the scores table
    database.all("SELECT testname, score, percent FROM scores").then(rows => {

    for (var row in rows) {
        //the line below was changed too...     
        viewModel.results.push({testname: rows[row][0], score: rows[row][1], percent: rows[row][2]});
    }, error => {
        console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
    })
}
```

Done. it works as expected now. Thanks TJ Vantoll for trying to help. Really Appreciated.

Comment: Also thanks for leaving your solution here for others to benefit from.

Comment: It's the least i could do.